# positioning a button child wihtin a list parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a to-do list. Whenever the user enters a new task, it is displayed as a list item. Within the list item I am attempting to position a button element, so that when the user clicks on it, the item can shift into another list - "completed tasks".

I am having a bit of trouble poistioning the button element within the list to suit my requirements. I am trying to posistion it equivalant to "right-aligned", at the end of the list element, so that the button is after the text has finished of the given to-do task (I hope that makes sense!)

HTML:

```
<div id="incomplete-tasks">
  <h4>INCOMPLETE TASKS</h4>
  <ul id="task-to-do">

  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #6363B6;
}

li button {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 80%;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function () {

  var taskinput = document.getElementById("task").value;  

  if (taskinput) {
    var tasktext = document.createTextNode(taskinput);
    var list = document.createElement("li");
    list.appendChild(tasktext);
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "completed";
    list.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById("task-to-do").appendChild(list);
    document.getElementById("task").value ="";
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a task");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, It may help you:

```
li button {
display: block;
width: auto;
padding: 1%;
clear:both;
float:right;
}
```

Try this float property It may help you.